# Default deleter on shared_ptr for a specific type

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Is it possible to give a `boost::shared_ptr` a default deleter for a certain type (that is not `delete`)?

Currently I have:

```
// .h
typedef boost::shared_ptr<SomeType> SomeTypePtr;
SomeTypePtr InitPtr(SomeType * p);



// .cpp
struct SomeTypeDeleter { ... };
SomeTypePtr InitPtr(SomeType * p)
{
  return SomeTypePtr(p, SomeTypeDeleter());
}
```

I would like to use a different default deleter, so I can skip the `InitPtr` method and instead use

```
SomeTypePtr(pSomeType);                // uses SomeTypeDeleter
SomeTypePtr(pSomeType, NullDeleter);   // uses specified deleter
```

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be a simple wrapper:

```
struct some_type_deleter
{
  // ...
};

template<class T>
class some_type_ptr
  : public boost::shared_ptr<T>
{
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<T> base_type;

public:
  template<class U>
  some_type_ptr(U* p)
    : base_type(p, some_type_deleter())
  {
  }

  template<class U, class D>
  some_type_ptr(U* p, D d)
    : base_type(p, d)
  {
  }

  template<class U, class A, class D>
  some_type_ptr(U* p, A a, D d)
    : base_type(p, a, d)
  {
  }
};
```

Not perfect, but does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. The default deleter isn't something customizable. A shared pointer with default deleter is actually smaller (internally) than one with a custom deleter. You can make your `InitPtr` function provide a default, though.